# Iterating 3800 records, taking too much time in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am facing issue with iterating list of records,
it's taking too much time to load the data on the screen, due to this performance is getting down.

I tried the following scenarios.

## html

```
 <select class="append"/>
```

## js

```
var listOfrecords = [{"name":"hello"},{},{}......etc];//assume 3800 records 

 using forEach
 =======================
listOfrecords.forEach(function(index,record){
   //I tried both
  $(".append").append('<option>'+record.name+'</option>');
        or
  $(".append").html('<option>'+record.name+'</option>');
})

 using for loop
=====================
for(var int i=0;i<=listOfrecords.length;i++){
  //I tried both
  $(".append").append('<option>'+listOfrecords[i].name+'</option>');
        or
  $(".append").html('<option>'+listOfrecords[i].name+'</option>');
 }

  using while loop
 ===================
  var i = listOfrecords.length;
  while(i--){
   //I tried both
  $(".append").append('<option>'+listOfrecords[i].name+'</option>');
        or
  $(".append").html('<option>'+listOfrecords[i].name+'</option>');
  }

  using for in
  ============
 for(var i in listOfrecords){
  //I tried both
  $(".append").append('<option>'+listOfrecords[i].name+'</option>');
        or
  $(".append").html('<option>'+listOfrecords[i].name+'</option>');

 }
```

The data is displayed on the screen, but it takes too much time.
Can anyone suggest me, is there any way to render the data faster.

Comment: You could first construct the HTML string, then pass the result over to jquery.

Comment: Build a single string and then execute a single `.append(html)` at the end.

Comment: @Archer i am not clear, can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @vallepuveerendrakumar He means do your loop, append to string instead of doing `.append(html)`. So `var str = ""` then in loop `str += html`. Once loop finishes do a single `.append(str)`

Comment: I would suggest, you should create a list using `ul li` and append a limited number of records like 100, 150 or 200 etc in it initially. Eventually if user scrolls down in list, you may add more if needed.

Comment: @MohammadUsman  yes but user wanted to see all the values at a time

Comment: @Adriani6 yes i tried that one also ,let me paste that code

Comment: var option;
listOfrecords.forEach(function(index,record){
   //I tried both
option += "<options>record[index]</options>"
  })
$(".append").append(option);
        or
  $(".append").html(option);

I tried using this also with others loops . but still it takes more time to load on screen in IE

Comment: This will help: https://howchoo.com/g/mmu0nguznjg/learn-the-slow-and-fast-way-to-append-elements-to-the-dom

Comment: Don't be [Schlemiel](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Comment: From everything I've read on this page I think the real answer is that your approach is all wrong.  If you think *need* a table with 30-50 rows that each have a dropdown with *3800* options then you're wrong.  I fully expect you to disregard this comment and carry on regardless, but the reason you're here asking the question is because your approach is wrong.

Comment: @Archer yes you are right, but i don't know who wrote this type of code, this is long back implemented. now i am trying to fix this issue.

Comment: If you have scope then I'd recommend considering replacing whatever requires this.  You can't make the browser render that much data quicker than it does.  Suggestions of Ajaxifying the dropdowns will help make it *look* better, but will be slower in the long run.  Is every dropdown different, or do they all contain the same options?

Comment: all dropdowns conatins same options ,

Comment: Okay, well I rendered 50 dropdowns with 3800 options, in a table, in less than 2 seconds.  Here... https://jsfiddle.net/evf5ze7v/1/

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the DOM is expensive - you're essentially telling the browser to traverse the DOM tree with every "append", and then insert another element. So each time you access the dom, you're making your bit of code exponentially more expensive to run. Since you're using a loop and accessing the DOM tree 3800 times, I can see why your browser would complain.

A better thing to do is to build an HTML string or DocumentFragment as you don't need to access the DOM with every item in your array.

```
var string = '';

for ( var i = 0, i < elements.length, i++ ) {

    string += '<option>' + elements.content + '</option>';

}

$('body').append(string);
```

Comment: I tried this also .  
in table ,I have to put this select box with 3800 options, for eack row

Comment: ...And you're wondering why this will be slow? So how many rows are in the table? It wouldn't matter which browser you used, all of them will struggle to load this. I would advise you look up lazy loading on a select box - something like the chosen jquery plugin has a search feature with a callback so you can lazy load search results. That way you will just have empty select boxes on each row of your table, and a much faster load time.

Comment: approx. 30 -50 rows . as its a dynamic data . so it will vary .

Comment: Yes so that's 30-50 multiplied by 3800. Can you imagine the load on the browser? I will try to find a link for you - I hope you are familiar with AJAX, as you will need to return the search results this way to append to the select box.

Comment: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax is a project fork of Chosen Jquery which has AJAX support. There's an example on the page of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and add values on a string, and then just call `.append` once.

> It's much quicker, with an approximately 9-10x speed increase

```js
var listOfrecords = [{"name":"hello"},{},{}......etc];//assume 3800 records 

var newOptions = '';

listOfrecords.forEach(function(index,record){
    newOptions += '<option>'+record.name+'</option>';
});

$(".append").append(newOptions); //only having to call append insert once
```

```html
<select class="append"/>
```

Font: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Comment: @vallepuveerendrakumar Try close development tools, please, and test it

Comment: How long does it take for it to iterate and append with my code? cuz i will try in my IE explorer and test it

Comment: in table ,I have to put this select box with 3800 options, for eack row . its taking around 25-30  secs to load